# How to create CSS for round, responsive, bootstrap button with border? Border is affecting pixels

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm wrestling with bootstrap CSS and am having trouble lining up the last couple of pixels.

I'm trying to create a responsive row of round images, followed by a round link/button to add a new image. The markup is like this

```
<div class="container">
    <div class='row'>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <a href="/url/to/object">
                <img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="https://pensivepool.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/josef-albers-study-for-homage-to-the-square-silkscreen-print-80774.jpg">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <a href="/url/to/object">
                <img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="https://pensivepool.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/josef-albers-study-for-homage-to-the-square-silkscreen-print-80774.jpg">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <a class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-responsive" href="#link_to_add_new">
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've put an example with css on jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/9fgd4972/

As you can see, the button is 1 or 2 pixels too high, and this is due to the extra width of the border. What is the best way to account for this border in the css, so that the circle remains responsive.

Also, what is the best way to vertically align the `+` text within that height.

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: link is now added! sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to change the border with a box-shadow.

About the vertical alignment you could position the icon (+) with position absolute, set all the values to 0 (top, right, bottom, left), margin and height to auto and max-height to the exactly height of the icon.

Like this:

```
box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #ccc;
```

And:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
padding: 0;
margin: auto;
height: auto;
max-height: 12px;
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alessiozuccotti/14v1f8rk/4/

Comment: only problem here is the + doesn't move with resize

Comment: @alessio thanks. This is a good start. But the bottom box shadow causes the link to no longer be round. Of course I could add a left shadow, but it seems hacky. Is this really the best way? For the line-height, this works at the current size, but is not responsive if the circle size changes. Do you have suggestion how to make this responsive?

Comment: @aw04 You're right, sorry, just update the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alessiozuccotti/14v1f8rk/4/

Comment: For the "+" alligment just give that specific element: "padding-top:28px;"

Comment: @Alessio, this works great, thanks! Will you update your answer?

Comment: @andyHarvey Yeah! :) I'm happy to hear I help you solving your problem! Good work!